# grep a particular content before a period

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to read/grep a particular word or content that is before a period (`.`).

e.g. `file1` has `abinaya.ashok` and I want to grep whatever is before the period (`.`) without hardcoding anything.

if I try

```
grep \.\ file1
```

it gives `abinaya.ashok`.
I've tried: `grep\*\.\ file1`

it doesn't give anything.Can we find it using grep commands or should we do it only using awk command? Any thoughts?

Comment: It's always trivial to select what you want and MUCH harder to not select what you do not want. Post a few lines of sample input and expected output that includes the case you think will be hardest to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `grep` for `PCRE` regex (for non-greedy and positive look-ahead), you can do:

```
echo 'abinaya.ashok' | grep -oP '.*?(?=\.)'
abinaya
```

Using `awk`:

```
echo 'abinaya.ashok' | awk -F\. '{print $1}'
abinaya
```

Comment: Not sure if OP may have a line like `freddy frog abinaya.ashok` and only want to see `abinaya`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ha! Good point. Will update if he cares to be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answers:) I want to grep the word/content before (.) without hardcoding i.e.abinaya.ashok.Bascially I want to kill a screen with its id so the content before dot is going to be a autogenerated number.Using script i want to kill the screen.

Comment: @javalearner I haven't hard coded anything in the answer. That `echo` statement is just to show that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following simple examples.

Including the dot:

```
$ echo abinaya.ashok | grep -o '.*[.]'
abinaya.
```

Without the dot:

```
$ echo abinaya.ashok | grep -o '^[^.]\+'
abinaya
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand you correctly:

```
sed -n 's/\..*//p' file1 | grep whatever
```

**sed** expression will print only part before dot (lines without dot are not printed).
Now use **grep** to search what you need.